# Call button click on a module using a variable for the button number

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I am working on a Excel VBA macro that has almost 200 buttons. I want to use the click events in one module.

I have seen that I have to change the event to Public and use:

Call userform1.commandbutton1_Click
 or
 userform1.commandbutton1_Click

I would like to change the number of the button with a variable in order to use a loop, but I don’t know how to do it.

I was able to do it of I want to change the button properties with:

userform1.Controls(“commandbutton” & i).caption = “test” but it's not working to for the "_Click"

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Value` property of the `Button` control:

```
Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i).Value = True
```